# Can we write $a \leq a$

Tags: inequality

I am proving some inequality and one of the steps i took is that i wrote $n+1 \leq n+1$ is it correct mathematically to write such thing ?

Note :
i was try to prove that $2^{n-1} \leq n! \leq n^{n} \space \space \forall n \in \mathbb{N^*}...P_n $

so i did it by induction and i got to $2^{n-1} \leq n! \leq (n+1)^n$

then i wrote that $2 \leq n+1 \leq n+1$ and i multiplied the inequalities side by side to get to $P_{n+1}$

Comment: The statement $a≤a$ is clearly true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a\leqslant b$ means $a <b$ or $a=b$.

So $a\leqslant a$.

Answer (score 2):

The "$\leq$" sign means less than or equal to. As $a=a$, or $n+1=n+1$, the equals sign can be correctly replaced by the less than or equal to sign ($\leq$).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the ''less than equal'' relation on $\Bbb N_0$ is defined as

$a\leq b \;:\Longleftrightarrow \;\exists c\in\Bbb N_0: a+c=b.$

So $a\leq a$ is satisfied for $c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

When we write $a\leq b$ we mean that $a$ is either equal or greater than $b$. Every number is obviously equal to himself, so $a\leq a$ for every number $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $a\leq a$ is correct.

$x\leq y$ means $x$ is not bigger than $y$.

Answer (score 0):

The binary relation $\leq$ is a partial order over $\mathbb{R}$, thus is satisfies the reflexivity, i.e. :

$$\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, \; a\leq a$$